# SQL Queries for a database

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, sql-server-2008

I have an assignment on DB. I am having some problems with my queries. I am new to SQL.
Here's my tables:

```
CREATE TABLE Employee (
employee_name varchar(20) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
street varchar(30) NOT NULL,
city varchar(20) NOT NULL
)

CREATE TABLE Works
(
employee_name varchar(20) NOT NULL,
department_name varchar(20) NOT NULL,
title varchar(10) NOT NULL,
salary int NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (employee_name),
FOREIGN KEY (employee_name) REFERENCES Employee,
FOREIGN KEY (department_name) REFERENCES Department
)

CREATE TABLE Department
(
department_name varchar(20),
cityvarchar(20),
PRIMARY KEY (department_name)
)

CREATE table Manages(
employee_name varchar(20) not null,
manager_name varchar (20) not null,
PRIMARY KEY(employee_name),
FOREIGN KEY(employee_name) REFERENCES Employee
)
```

Find employee names who live in different cities from their department.
Here's my code:

```
SELECT E.employee_name
FROM Employee E
JOIN Department D
ON E.city = D.city
WHERE E.city <> 'Roma';
```

Find employee names who live in the same city and in the same street with their managers.
Here's my code:

```
SELECT E.employee_name
FROM Employee E
INNER JOIN Department D
ON E.city = D.city
INNER JOIN Manages M
ON E.employee_name = M.employee_name
WHERE city='Roma' AND street='Main street';
```

What am I doing wrong?
Thank you in advance! :)

Comment: I don't think that 'Roma' and 'Main Street' are part of the question you are trying to answer...

Comment: @NicolaFerraro Yes, you're right. I can clearly see my mistake. Thank you :)

Comment: You need to join on foreign keys. For your first question, look at the table definitions; what joins the employee table to the works table and then, what joins the works table to the department table? Join on these keys and use the 'Where' clause to filter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's how you might accomplish the first task (employees who live in a city other than that of their department):

```
SELECT E.employee_name
  FROM Employee E JOIN Works W
    ON E.employee_name = W.employee_name
  JOIN Department D
    ON W.departent_name = D.department_name
 WHERE D.city <> E.city;
```

In order to determine the department in which a given employee works, you need to join to the `Works` table.

I have to admit that the vertical partition of employee data into `Employee` and `Works` tables is a bit odd - there is no real reason for these two to be separate tables (it's a 1-1 relationship). For that matter `Manages` need not be a separate table either.

Hopefully this can get you on the right path for the second query.

Comment: This works for me. Any advice about where can I find good tutorials online? Thank you for you help :)